# Lucene Nested Boolean equivalent to OR

Tags: .net, lucene, lucene.net

Each item in my index has a field called `TYPE`. This is either `"Document", "Blog" or "Forum"`

Users can can choose which TYPE's they want to search for, but if searching for "Document" I need to add  a range query so that `"Document"` types are only returned if its `STARTDATE` field falls into an a valid range

```
 using (var searcher = new IndexSearcher(_directory, false))
      {

    var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29);

    BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
    BooleanQuery innerTypeFilterQuery = new BooleanQuery();

    long today = Convert.ToInt64(LuceneDate.Today().Value);

    foreach (string filterItem in filterItems)
    {
      TermQuery filterItemQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("Type", filterItem));
      innerTypeFilterQuery.Add(filterItemQuery, Occur.SHOULD);

      if (filterItem == "Document")
      {
        innerTypeFilterQuery.Add(NumericRangeQuery.NewLongRange("StartDate", null, today, true, true), Occur.MUST);
      }
    }

    if (innerTypeFilterQuery.Clauses.Count > 0)
    {
      booleanQuery.Add(innerTypeFilterQuery, Occur.MUST);
    }

    Sort sort = new Sort(new SortField(LuceneGeneric.IndexFields.StartDate, Lucene.Net.Search.SortField.LONG, true));
    var hits = searcher.Search(booleanQuery, null, LuceneContentWidgetResult.HITS_LIMIT, sort).ScoreDocs;
    var results = _mapLuceneContentWidgetSearchResultsToDataList(hits, searcher);
    analyzer.Close();
    searcher.Dispose();
    return results;
}
```

My query looks like this:

{+(Type:Document +StartDate:[* TO 20141022000000] Type:BlogPost Type:ForumQuestion Type:ForumIdea Type:ForumIdeaList Type:ForumDiscussion)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you want to achieve.

Let's say you have a document:

```
title=foo
date=100 // using numeric value for simplicity
```

Here's your truth table for both types of queries (all done as a single `BooleanQuery`)

```
   query                      |   doc match result
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
title:foo +date:[80 TO 150]   | true (both matched)
title:foo +date:[10 TO 20]    | false (date hasn't matched even though title matched)
title:boo +date:[80 TO 150]   | true (date matched but title hasn't)
title:boo +date:[10 TO 20]    | false (none matched)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
title:foo date:[80 TO 150]    | true (both matched)
title:foo date:[10 TO 20]     | true (date hasn't matched but title matched)
title:boo date:[80 TO 150]    | true (date matched but title hasn't)
title:boo date:[10 TO 20]     | false (none matched)
```

As you can see, date is `MUST` for the first 4 table rows and `SHOULD` for the bottom 4 rows.

Q> Im unsure where to add, do i need to add another boolean query to `innerTypeFilterQuery`
A> Again, please explain what kind of matching result you want but if any result from the above truth table satisfies your requirements, you can add it to the same query.

Edit: I think your query should look like as this:

```
+((Type:Document +StartDate:[* TO 20141022000000]) Type:BlogPost Type:ForumQuestion Type:ForumIdea Type:ForumIdeaList Type:ForumDiscussion)
```

So yes, you will need a separate boolean query to wrap both Document constraints.

Comment: Thankyou - using your example what i would like is when searching for title="foo" I would also like to add the range search. Foo in this case is a constant I know will be there. For other searches I would not include the range. basically documents have an expiry date so i want these omitted.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question into a *complete* truth table? As now I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry Ive not got any experience with truth tables, I hope my edit is sufficent

Comment: Im afraid that didn't work - I have included my query code plus the Query string if it would be possible for you to look

Comment: Edited again - sorry, misunderstood your previous explanation.

Comment: Sorry for the extended discussion but how could I create that programatically

Comment: Each element with `+` is a `MUST` and without is `SHOULD`. The document bit with start date should be in a separate boolean query which is added to the wrapping boolean query as SHOULD. Just try creating such query, convert it to string and verify if you got the right result.

Comment: Cool thats what I'm doing right now. Thanks for all your help with this